# How to search for a string in a CLOB and display the value after it in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to do this within one query, I am not sure if it is possible. I have a table called STORE_VALUES with columns CODE and VALUE. CODE is the PKEY of this table. VALUE is a CLOB column containing a large XML object

| CODE | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| DataSet1 | ....some xml... <Version>1</Version>...some more xml |
| DataSet2 | ....some xml... <Version>5</Version>...some more xml |

I need to look for the first instance of the tag <Version> and show the number after it (There is more than one instance but I only care about the first)
I believe I need to use dbms_lob.instr but I can't figure out how to do that. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

This is what I have tried so far but it is only showing me whatever is after that value I need (So it displays </Version> followed by the rest of the clob)

SELECT code, dbms_lob.substr(VALUE, dbms_lob.instr(VALUE,'<Version>'),dbms_lob.INSTR(VALUE,'</Version>' )) from STORE_VALUES;

Answer (score 0):

Using the limited information you provided I created a sample table with some sample data. The one caveat that you must remember here is that you have to traverse the xml. Since I only have 'Version' in the CLOB column, I only needed to use `Version` in my query below. However, if it had a parent element like for example `Versions` than I would have to adjust my query to do something like `'/Versions/Version'` in order to get to that element in the xml.

```
    --table ddl  
    CREATE TABLE STORE_VALUES
   (    CODE VARCHAR2(20), 
        VALUE CLOB
   ) ;

     -- potential insert statement. --
     INSERT INTO STORE_VALUES (CODE, VALUE) VALUES ('1', '<Version>1</Version>');
     INSERT INTO STORE_VALUES (CODE, VALUE) VALUES ('2', '<Version>5</Version>');

 --possible query dependent on full xml

SELECT
    extractvalue(
        xmltype(
            dbms_lob.substr(
                value, 3000
            )
        ), 'Version'
    ) version_el
FROM
    store_values;
```

Comment: I only wish to get the number after the version tag. In the example above, I want to get 1 and 5 displayed.

Comment: Thanks but I am dealing with many different types of XML objects. As such the Version tag will be under different parent elements. I was hoping to be able to do this with simple string functions where I only look for the first occurrence of "<Version>" and display the value after it, as that will work in all cases.

Comment: It seems the VALUE column isn't true xml as it has some string before it and after it, so XML parsing does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `VALUE` column is XML, you could try using the XML functions available to extract the value. The actual XPath to extract the "Version" from the XML may vary depending on how your XML document is structured.

#### Query

```sql
WITH
    store_values (code, VALUE)
    AS
        (SELECT 'DataSet1',
                TO_CLOB ('<doc><attr1>abc</attr1><Version>1</Version><attr2>def</attr2></doc>')
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'DataSet2',
                TO_CLOB ('<doc><attr1>ghi</attr1><Version>5</Version><attr2>jkl</attr2></doc>')
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT code, EXTRACTVALUE (xmltype (VALUE), '/doc/Version/text()') AS version_no
  FROM store_values;
```

#### Result

```
       CODE    VERSION_NO
___________ _____________
DataSet1    1
DataSet2    5
```

## Update

Since the `VALUE` column does not contain true XML, you can extract the the value using REGEX expressions. The query below will give the same result as above.

```sql
WITH
    store_values (code, VALUE)
    AS
        (SELECT 'DataSet1',
                TO_CLOB ('<doc><attr1>abc</attr1><Version>1</Version><attr2>def</attr2></doc>')
           FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'DataSet2',
                TO_CLOB ('<doc><attr1>ghi</attr1><Version>5</Version><attr2>jkl</attr2></doc>')
           FROM DUAL)
SELECT code,
       REGEXP_REPLACE (REGEXP_SUBSTR (VALUE, '<Version>.*</Version>'), '<[^>]*>')     AS version_no
  FROM store_values;
```

Comment: If only the OP did not clearly state that the XML is rather large. In that case the sole XML-parsing of the CLOB would consume considerable amount of time.

Other than that, your answer is perfect.

Comment: XML parsing does not seem to work as the column does not seem to be true XML so I have to resort to looking up substrings to look for <Version>